# Angular2 module circular dependencies?

Tags: angular

For example, module `a` depend the component of module `b`, module depend the pipe of module a, how to solve the problem?thanks.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is solved by adding third module with common dependencies.

Comment: Better yet an interface.

Comment: interface also has to be exported/imported unless it is defined in typings.